# The dynamic dropdown gets stuck on the first one created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have a dynamic dropdown that can expand when the user presses the enter button. However, I am having difficulty changing the text inside the dropdown button because, for some reason, the ID of my dropdown button gets stuck on dropdown number 2 (which happens to be the first dropdown created when the user presses the enter button).

```
<form id="form-atr">
    <div class="form-group" id="df2">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownButton1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Modifier
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownMenu1">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="changeButtonName('Public', 'dropdownButton1')">Public</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="changeButtonName('Private', 'dropdownButton1')">Private</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="changeButtonName('Protected', 'dropdownButton1')">Protected</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="atribut[]" placeholder="Nama Atribut">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="inputs">

    </div>
</form>
```

The input that can receive the enter button is "atribut[]". and I included this dynamic dropdown inside a div named "inputs."

This is how I code in javascript:

```
const input_atr = document.getElementsByName('atribut[]');
input_atr.forEach(function(input) {
    input.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
      let div = document.getElementById("inputs");
      addInput(event, div, 'atribut[]');
    });
});

let counter = 1; // Starting from 1 because I already have dropdown number 1.
```

let's say I have already created 4 new dropdowns, then the counter value is now 5.

```
function addInput(event, div, name) {
    var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if (key == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
        counter++;
        const newModifier = document.createElement("button");
        const dropdownMenu = document.createElement("div");
        const newInput = document.createElement("input");

        const dropdownButtonId = "dropdownButton" + counter;
        console.log('dropdownButtonId',dropdownButtonId); // dropdownButton5
        
        newModifier.type = 'button';
        newModifier.className = 'btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle';
        newModifier.textContent = "Modifier";
        
        newModifier.id = dropdownButtonId;
        console.log('newModifier.id',newModifier.id); // dropdownButton5
        
        newModifier.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
        dropdownMenu.className = 'dropdown-menu';
        
        dropdownMenu.id = "dropdownMenu" + counter;
        console.log('dropdownMenu.id',dropdownMenu.id); // dropdownMenu5
        
        dropdownMenu.appendChild(createDropdownItem("Public", dropdownButtonId));
        dropdownMenu.appendChild(createDropdownItem("Private", dropdownButtonId));
        dropdownMenu.appendChild(createDropdownItem("Protected", dropdownButtonId));
        newInput.type = 'text';
        newInput.name = name;
        newInput.onkeydown = function(event) {
            addInput(event, div, name);
        };
        newInput.className = 'form-control';
        div.appendChild(newModifier);
        div.appendChild(dropdownMenu);
        div.appendChild(newInput);
    }
}

function createDropdownItem(text, buttonId) {
    console.log('createDropdownItem', buttonId); // dropdownButton5 3 times in a row
    const dropdownItem = document.createElement("a");
    dropdownItem.className = "dropdown-item";
    dropdownItem.href = "#";
    dropdownItem.textContent = text;
    dropdownItem.onclick = function() {
        changeButtonName(text, buttonId);
        console.log('changeButtonName', buttonId); // But here its says dropdownButton2???
    };
    return dropdownItem;
}

function changeButtonName(menuName, buttonId) {
    const dropdownButton = document.getElementById(buttonId);
    dropdownButton.textContent = menuName;
}
```

Because the value of buttonId is always dropdownButton2, all the newly created dropdowns cannot perform the changeButtonName function, causing their textContent to only modify the dropdown number 2. I completely don't understand why the value stops at dropdownButton2 when precisely in the console, it showed the value dropdownButton5 previously.

I've tried something like this:

```
function createDropdownItem(text, buttonId) {
    console.log('createDropdownItem', buttonId);
    const dropdownItem = document.createElement("a");
    dropdownItem.className = "dropdown-item";
    dropdownItem.href = "#";
    dropdownItem.textContent = text;
    dropdownItem.onclick = function(id) {
        return function() {
            changeButtonName(text, "dropdownButton" + id);
            console.log('changeButtonName', id);
        };
    }(buttonId);
    return dropdownItem;
}
```

But still not work. It's keep stuck at number 2 (the first one created dynamically). I am a beginner in using JavaScript, so I really appreciate your help. I sincerely thank you for any kind of assistance.

[This is what the console shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqL55.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have issues with IDs and keeping track of the different "attributes". Consider the following example where there are NO IDs involved in the form. To organize the different "attributes" I made fieldsets that have there own modifier, name and value.

I know this is very different from the code that you present, but I hope that you can see the idea. I try to stick to the intention with the HTML form element and its form fields.

Now, I don't know how you would like the data from the form, but I make JSON array.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  // form.elements.attribute is either nodeList or <fieldset>; make it an array
  let fieldsets = (form.elements.attribute.length) ? form.elements.attribute : [form.elements.attribute];
  // return values based on the fieldsets
  let fieldsets_data = [...fieldsets].map(fieldset => {
    return {
      modifier: fieldset.elements.modifier.value,
      name: fieldset.elements.name.value,
      value: fieldset.elements.value.value
    };
  });
  console.log(fieldsets_data);
});

document.forms.form01.addattribute.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let template = document.getElementById('fieldset');
  let fieldset_clone = template.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
  if (form.elements.attribute) {
    let fieldsets_length = form.elements.attribute.length;
    // form.elements.attribute is either nodeList or <fieldset>; pick the last or only one
    let fieldset_last = (fieldsets_length) ? form.elements.attribute.item(fieldsets_length - 1) : form.elements.attribute;
    // append after the last fieldset
    fieldset_last.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', fieldset_clone);
  } else {
    form.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', fieldset_clone);
  }
});
```

```html
<template id="fieldset">
 <fieldset name="attribute">
    <select name="modifier" required>
      <option value="">Modifier</option>
      <option value="1">Public</option>
      <option value="2">Private</option>
      <option value="3">Protected</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Value" name="value">
  </fieldset>
</template>

<form name="form01">
  <fieldset name="attribute">
    <select name="modifier" required>
      <option value="">Modifier</option>
      <option value="1">Public</option>
      <option value="2">Private</option>
      <option value="3">Protected</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Value" name="value">
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" name="addattribute">Add attribute</button>
</form>
```